# Does a wireless access point with PoE ports exist?

Tags: wireless-access-point, power-over-ethernet

I'm currently making my own, because I have yet to find a company that makes an access point with PoE ports.  I have seen several APs that are powered by PoE, but they don't pass 48V to their ethernet ports (if they even have those).  It would be nice to buy something off the shelf, and I'm surprised that (if I'm right) no such thing exists.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no need to find one that specifically supports it; any can do so with [a fairly inexpensive adapter](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10759).

Comment: Yay SparkFun! My favorite toy store!

Comment: I guess it's just that I was looking for something more nicely packaged so that you don't have N adapters hooked up to N PoE devices, which then has multiple wall warts, etc etc.  I wonder what the difference is between active and passive adapters?  The link you posted is for a passive adapter which looks a lot different than the one I am currently using -- http://www.tp-link.us/products/details/?categoryid=234&model=TL-POE150S

Comment: Reading further in that product description, it just puts whatever power you supply on the ethernet cable lines used by PoE.  The 802.3af compliant boxes negotiate power requirements with the device at the other end of the cable.

Comment: Yours is fully 802.3af compliant. Also, [this](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1352).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Well, it looks like I'll just wait and see if anyone else has seen one.  I'm hoping for something more like what I have built up -- basically a router running DD-WRT, plus 48 and 12VDC power supplies and just one AC power connection.  You'd think a company could easily package it up a lot nicer that what I'm creating, but perhaps you're right, and no one really needs something like this (except for me, since I'm picky).

Comment: Nothing at all wrong with being picky.

Comment: An access point is going to have one ethernet port and provide WiFi connectivity. One such direct POE device is the PicoStation M2. You're actually describing a combined wireless router with built-in ethernet switch that you wish to have POE ports, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Most installations use a PoE capable switch positioned to optimize wiring considerations (shorter runs, easier location to access etc). The access point(s) are positioned to optimize wireless considerations - range, spacing, RF obstructions. This is where PoE is nice as it allows one wire run to the access point and a UPS on the switch powers it and all the access points attached.

As well you can't really pass on PoE as there isn't really enough power for long runs or multiple devices. The wires aren't that thick and can't pass a lot of current.

For those reasons the product you desire just isn't in much demand.

Answer (score 0):

Ubiquity Unifi access point do. But they are 12 volt I think. They do come with the power adapter to supply the power and on the access point end they just plug in.

http://www.ubnt.com/unifi

Answer (score 0):

http://www.planet.com.tw/en/product/product.php?id=39843#appl
Around $250

Using it to connect Remote Office with 3 POE Cameras.
Cannot cross the road with Cabling (Power/CAT5)